# Buscar campos por una fecha o un rango a través de un formulario

Tags: php, html

tengo un pequeño problema y espero me puedan ayudar.
Explico, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
$select = "SELECT colonia, COUNT( colonia ) FROM scpd_incidencia GROUP BY colonia ORDER BY COUNT( colonia) DESC ";

echo "<form id='buscar' action='' method='get'>
    <h1>Buscar delito por fecha</h1>
    <section id ='sec1'>
        Fecha inicio:  <input type='text' name='fecha_ini' id='buscar' placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd' autocomplete='off' required>
    </section>
    <section id='sec2'>
        Fecha fin:  <input type='text' name='fecha_fin' id='buscar' placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd' autocomplete='off'>
    </section>
    <button class='btn btn-primary 'type='submit' form='buscar' onclick='alrt()'>Buscar</button>
</form>";

if($fecha_ini == ''){
echo "<script>
    function alrt(){
        alert('Debes agregar una fecha');
        window.location.href='./estadistica-por-colonia'
    }
</script>";
}else {
   $select .= " WHERE fecha_delito = '$fecha_ini'";
}
selectQuery($select);

?>
```

Formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver tengo una consulta `select` la cual funciona sin problema, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 debajo aparece tengo un `form` donde aparecen 2 `inputs` con los cuales pretendo que al momento de que el usuario agregue la `fecha_ini` y de click en `buscar` ejecute el `$select .=`, sin embargo no lo ejecuta y sale un error de sintaxis, supongo que es porque al momento de añadir el `$select .=` el `WHERE = ...` lo añade al final 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien lo que pretendo es hacer es:

1.- que el query se ejecute cuando se añada solamente el campo `fecha_ini`

2.- que el query se ejecute cuando se añadan los campos `fecha_ini` `fecha_fin`

Alguna idea, apoyo, asesoramiento, etc..

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo completando al final tu código funcionaría ... y lo mismo sería para fecha_fin

```js
<?php
$select = "SELECT colonia, COUNT( colonia ) FROM scpd_incidencia";

echo "<form id='buscar' action='' method='get'>
    <h1>Buscar delito por fecha</h1>
    <section id ='sec1'>
        Fecha inicio:  <input type='text' name='fecha_ini' id='buscar' placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd' autocomplete='off' required>
    </section>
    <section id='sec2'>
        Fecha fin:  <input type='text' name='fecha_fin' id='buscar' placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd' autocomplete='off'>
    </section>
    <button class='btn btn-primary 'type='submit' form='buscar' onclick='alrt()'>Buscar</button>
</form>";

if($fecha_ini == ''){
echo "<script>
    function alrt(){
        alert('Debes agregar una fecha');
        window.location.href='./estadistica-por-colonia'
    }
</script>";
}else {
   $select .= " WHERE fecha_delito = '$fecha_ini'";
}
$select .= " GROUP BY colonia ORDER BY COUNT( colonia) DESC "
selectQuery($select);

?>
```

Comment: hola @Augusto he probado lo que me dices y si parece que funciona, con el respecto al puto 2 de mi pregunta tienes alguna idea de como hacer funcionar los `if` de manera que si agrega solo la `fecha_ini` se ejecute el `$select` y que si agrega `$fecha_ini` y `$fecha_fin` se ejecute igual.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
if ((isset($_GET["fecha_ini"]) && isset($_GET["fecha_fin"]) && ($_GET["fecha_ini"] != "" || $_GET["fecha_fin"] != "")) {
$select = "SELECT colonia, COUNT( colonia ) FROM scpd_incidencia";
     if ($_GET["fecha_ini"] != "") {
        $select .= " (fecha_ini like '%$_GET[fecha_ini]%') ";
     }               
     if ($_GET["fecha_fin"] != "") {
        if ($_GET["fecha_ini"] != "") {
           $select .= " and ";
           }
        $select .= " fecha_out = " . $_GET["fecha_out "];
     }
```

Éso debería hacer que lo busque.

Yo también tenía el mismo problema y éso me lo solucionó.

Comment: Gracias, checo tu codigo. slaudos

Answer (score 0):

No recuerdo bien pero trata de ejecutar tu consulta en este orden.

SELECT colonia, COUNT( colonia ) FROM scpd_incidencia WHERE fecha_delito = '$fecha_ini' GROUP BY colonia ORDER BY COUNT( colonia) DESC

ve que te sale cuando la ejecutas.

te recomiendo leer este link para que veas cual es el orden en que se ejecutan las sentencias sql.

[Ejecución de sentencias SQL](https://sql-listo.com/t-sql/orden-de-ejecucion-de-sentencias-sq/)

Saludos